# Ballot Box (☐) type symbol between the string while retrieving

Tags: mysql, servlets

I am using **MySQL** database and **Servlet** to fetch the values from the table. When I retrieve the values from the table I get **'☐'** symbol between the string

For example - 
The value in the database is stored as `D2` but when i retrieve it using servlet I get `D☐2`. How can this '☐' symbol can be removed?

Comment: that's not a ballot box. it's one of the commonly-used "character does not exist" glyphs in fonts. if a particular character hasn't had an "image" defined for it, you get that box.

Comment: @MarcB -  I am using a basic select statement to retrieve the value - 
`select emp_id from employee limit 1`.

Comment: so probably you've got a character-set mismatch somewhere. stored (say) utf-8 in the database, but are retrieving/displaying it in some other charset.

Comment: It was a character-set mismatch. The table's collation is utf-8 whereas the columns were stored as utf-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this because of the collation mismatch. Check the charset of the table and the charset of the columns in that table. They should be the same

Comment: Yes, The charset of the columns were in UTF-16 and the charset of the table is UTF-8. I changed it. Thanks.